# Passing value beetween activity and non-activity

Tags: android

My application reads database from non-activity class and populates spinner with data from database. Then user selects one value from a spinner an confirms it with a button. Now I need that value, back in non-activity class for further coding.

I tried with `return` but beacuse code for confirm button is `public void onClick(View v)`, `return` doesn't work.
Where should I place `return`, that I could get slected value in my non-activity class when I press a button or if there is any other way to do that.

Code if it is unclear what I'm trying to do.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
/*private List<String> Banka;
private Cursor cBanka;*/
private MyDatabase db;
Spinner spinner;
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPotrdi);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    loadSpinnerData();
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String bank=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Intent next= new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChooseLocation.class);
            startActivity(next);

        }
    });
    }



private void loadSpinnerData() {
db = new MyDatabase(this);

List<String> banks = db.getBanka();
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, banks);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
//Log.d("wtf", "listview: " + spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                           long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String label = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Izbrali ste: " + label,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    //cBanka.close();
    db.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Your question is not clear. From where do you want to send your data. And to which class?

Comment: I want to send it from MainActivity to MyDatabase class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to return anything. Just add a method to `MyDatabase` class and call that method from `MainActivity`.

MainActivity :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String bank=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        db = new MyDatabase(MainActivity.this); // if needed
        db.setBank(bank);   // or any other name you want
    }
});
```

And in `MyDatabase`,

```
public class MyDatabase{
    public String selectedBank = "";

    public void setBank(String bank) {   // or any other name you want
        selectedBank = bank;
        // use your data for whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: Great comment, but I want it other way around, with click on button i want to send selected item from spinner to MyDatabase

Comment: What do you exactly mean by sending data. I think by this, we are sending the data to MyDatabase

Comment: quick question, how can I use my data in other methods in MyDatabase class?

Comment: It depends on your requirement. Can you share the code?

Comment: Declare a field variable and set the value of this field variable inside `setBank()`. Check the edited answer.

Comment: I need it as a variable in my method, that will serve ma as an arguments in  db.query

Comment: Now you can pass this variable to your query. Like `db.query("select * from database where bank = " + selectedBank)`

Comment: Thank you, that would be all.

Answer (score 0):

As you used `db.getBanka()`, you can for sure use `db.setWhateverIWant(passedData)` and in your `non-activity` class you have a set method:

```
public void setWhateverIWant(Obj passedData){
    this.myData = passedData;
}
```